# Extract many phone numbers using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

I want to extract phone numbers from following regex. It extracts all phone number formats when I input numbers one by one but not when I input 2 or more numbers in one string.

```
@"^\+?(\d[\d-. ]+)?(\([\d-. ]+\))?[\d-. ]+\d$";
```

Comment: Can you us few different sample phone numbers?

Comment: Are they comma separated or in the same string or with the new line..?

Comment: What is defined as phone number for you?

Answer (score 3):

Of course it won't extract multiple numbers. The expression starts with `^` and ends with `$`, so if the string contains anything other than a single phone number, the regular expression will fail to match.

One solution is to remove those start and end characters, and then loop to extract the numbers one at a time.

```
Regex rePhone = new Regex(@"\+?(\d[\d-. ]+)?(\([\d-. ]+\))?[\d-. ]+\d");
Match m = rePhone.Match(inputString);
while (m.Success)
{
    string phone = m.Value;
    m = m.NextMatch();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

for extract all phone Numbers you can try this Regex :

```
((\+|\+\s|\d{1}\s?|\()(\d\)?\s?[-\.\s\(]??){8,}\d{1}|\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4})
```

its math often phone numbers.
you can check yor phone numbers with this Regex in **[Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/3fhlyJ/2)**